# ssh hangs in Ubuntu MaaS heterogeneous cluster

Tags: networking, ssh, arm, ubuntu

I have the following issue when using ssh on my local network.

I have setup a small cluster of Xeon machines using MAAS. I have installed Ubuntu Server 12.04 on all machines and configured local network 192.168.100.0/24. Machines are connected through a TpLink TL-SG-1024 switch. ssh works fine between these Xeons.

I have connected some ARM boards running Ubuntu 13.04 to this cluster, without adding them to MAAS. However, I have manually configured /etc/maas/dhcpd.conf such that these boards get a fix IP(v4) address in the same local network 192.168.100.0/24. Boards get the corresponding IP and ping works between them and each of the Xeon machines. However, ssh doesn't work - it hangs. Here is the output of `ssh -vvv ubuntu@octa02` (from one of the Xeon machines)

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to octa02 [192.168.100.82] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "octa02" from file "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:15
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
```

The same thing happens when I try ssh from ARM board to Xeon board. The only difference is that ssh version on ARM boards is:

```
OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
```

So, I have compiled the 5.9 version on ARM but the result is the same. I have also compiled the 6.1 version on Xeon and it also hangs:

```
ssh -vvv ubuntu@octa02

OpenSSH_6.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.100.82 [192.168.100.82] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.1
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.168.100.82" from file "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
```

Furthermore, ssh 6.1 between ARM boards works. But ssh 6.1 to ssh 5.9 doesn't work.

The strangest thing is the following: I have connected the small boards to an external network. Xeon cluster master is also connected to this network. And ssh between master and ARM boards works through this network (and there are different versions of ssh: 5.9 on Xeon and 6.1 on ARM).

Thanks for reading this long post. Do you have any suggestions?